# How to use enumerateNodeWithName in Swift 2.0?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I wrote a game with XCode 6.4 and want to port it now to Swift 2.0 using XCode 7.0 beta.

I have an issue with following code

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName(kShipName) {
    node, stop in
    shipNode = node
}
```

When I try to build I get the error

```
Cannot invoke 'enumerateChildNodesWithName' with an argument list of type '(String, (_, _) -> _)'
```

How do I have to change the call? I really tried a lot of different things :-(

Thanks!

Comment: Show the context, especially how you define `kShipName`.

Comment: What is the type of `shipNode`? My guess would be you're assigning an `SKNode` to a `SKSpriteNode` without casting, which causes the whole thing to fail type-checking.

Comment: @rickster: Thanks, this was the right thing :-)
Thanks a lot for the quick answers!

Comment: Glad to help! Converted my comment to an answer so you can accept.

Comment: Of course thanks to Mundi, too :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `shipNode` is defined elsewhere as having type `SKSpriteNode`, you can't just assign `node` to that variable in your closure. That's because `node` is of type `SKNode`, and you can't assign from a more general type to a more specific type without a cast. Try this instead:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName(kShipName) {
    node, stop in
    shipNode = node as! SKSpriteNode 
}
```

The reason you're seeing the cryptic error message is because you have a type error in a single-statement closure — that makes the compiler uncertain about whether you're trying to have an implicit return statement in the closure, which in turn makes it unsure of the closure's return type, which in turn makes it think you're passing an invalid parameter type to `enumerateChildNodesWithName`.

Comment: Works perfect!
Thank you very much :-)